# How to pass system system properties "-D" on gradle

Tags: gradle, networking, proxy, build.gradle, gradlew

As per the docs.gradle.org, below config can be setup on the gradle.properties either project level and system level but I want to pass below variable using ./gradlew.bat command as argument:

```
systemProp.http.proxyHost=www.somehost.org
systemProp.http.proxyPort=8080
systemProp.http.proxyUser=userid
systemProp.http.proxyPassword=password
systemProp.http.nonProxyHosts=*.nonproxyrepos.com|localhost
```

How can i pass "-D" option using ./gradlew.bat command

Answer (score 1):

"-D" option work only,if below configuration in the gradlew or gradlew.bat file :

**For Windows, gradlew.bat**

```
set CLASSPATH=%APP_HOME%\gradle\wrapper\gradle-wrapper.jar
.
.
.
@rem Add default JVM options by parsing command line. Anything starting with -D is option to java.
:SYSTEM_PROPS_EXTRACT
set _OPTION=%1
set prefix1=%_OPTION:~0,2%
if "%prefix1%" == "-D" (

  SET DEFAULT_JVM_OPTS=%DEFAULT_JVM_OPTS% %_OPTION%=%2%

)
shift
if not "%~1"=="" goto SYSTEM_PROPS_EXTRACT
```

echo Default JVM Options: %DEFAULT_JVM_OPTS%
.
.
.
.
@rem Execute Gradle
"%JAVA_EXE%" %DEFAULT_JVM_OPTS% %JAVA_OPTS% %GRADLE_OPTS% 
"-Dorg.gradle.appname=%APP_BASE_NAME%"
-classpath "%CLASSPATH%" org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain %CMD_LINE_ARGS%

**For Linux, gradlew [shell]**

```
for var in "$@"
do

    prefix=${var:0:2}
    if [[ $prefix == "-D" ]] ; then
    DEFAULT_JVM_OPTS=$DEFAULT_JVM_OPTS" "$var
    fi
done
function splitJvmOpts() {
    JVM_OPTS=("$@")
}
eval splitJvmOpts $DEFAULT_JVM_OPTS $JAVA_OPTS $GRADLE_OPTS
JVM_OPTS[${#JVM_OPTS[*]}]="-Dorg.gradle.appname=$APP_BASE_NAME"
echo "JVM_OPTS :""${JVM_OPTS[@]}"
```

exec "$JAVACMD" "${JVM_OPTS[@]}"
-classpath "$CLASSPATH" org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain "$@"

And finally the proxy option to use `gradlew build -Dhttp.proxyHost=www-xxx.com -Dhttp.proxyPort=80 -Dhttp.proxyUser=user1 -Dhttp.proxyPassword=user1 -Dhttp.auth.ntlm.domain=COMMON`

Answer (score 0):

As per the [docs](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_environment.html#sec:accessing_the_web_via_a_proxy):

> Configuring an HTTP or HTTPS proxy (for downloading dependencies, for example) is done **via standard JVM system properties**.

Means, you could also do

```
gradlew.bat -Dhttp.proxyHost=www.somehost.org -DproxyPort=8080 tasks
```

to achieve the same.